# GRUB disappeared after recent Ubuntu 12/Win7 install?

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, windows-7

I recently installed Win7 and Ubuntu 12 on a new build.

Installed windows first, as recommended, and then Ubuntu on the remaining unused drive space.

Everything was working fine, grub allowed me to dual boot properly. Until this morning - switched the machine on, and it booted into windows - no grub.

I'm wondering if a recent windows update may have overwritten the MBR?

So..

- What's most likely to have caused this?
- How do I get grub back?
- How do I stop it happening again in the future?

Thanks!

Comment: Install EasyBCD community edition on Windows 7. Goto new entry -> then Make a entry using "Grub 2". Change "Neo****" to "Ubuntu 12.04" - > Go to Deployment -> Write to MBR

Comment: Try [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Answer (score 3):

As Mitch has suggested you will need to run "Boot Repair"

You will need to do this using a Live CD/USB see here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows for full instructions

Comment: Ok thanks I'll try that - but I still don't understand why it happened. It's not something that I want to have to do regularly!

Comment: I'm afraid I can't tell you how it happened but I can say that it should not be a common occurrence. I have set up several machines for dual boot and never known it to happen unless Windows is installed after Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that Windows was hibernated ?

When you power on after hibernation the hibernated system 
is starting - you do not get a boot menu.

So maybe there is nothing wrong with your dual boot.
You will know after rebooting.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same problem, I had hibernated once. After that the GRUB stopped showing!